# React undefined props issues

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a question about my code.

In the SearchBar.js, I got error, which is undefined props.
I have two question, if it is undefined why the if statement does not invoke and 
I don't understand why props is undefined because I think I pass props properly from parent component to child component( SearchBar.js)

enter code here

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import ShopList from './components/ShopList';

class App extends React.Component {

    state ={ title: [], text: ''}

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({title:["javascript","react","redux","c++","java"]})
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="split left">
                <div className="centered">
                    <SearchBar handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} handleChange={this.handleChange} userinput={this.state.text}/>
                    <ShopList shops={this.state.title}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="split right">
                <div className="centered">

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));


SearchBar.js

import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render(){
    if(!this.props){
        return <div>Loding..</div>
    }
    return (
        <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="inline field">                
                <input onChange={this.props.handleChange} className="myinput" type="text" style={{width: '85%'}} value={props.userinput}/>
                <button className="ui primary button"  type="submit">button</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: `value={props.userinput}` should be `value={this.props.userinput}`

Comment: this.props is {} If it’s empty, which is true. And button is type submit by default.

Comment: Thank you I fixed it!  but I have one more question why do I need to pass event argument for onSubmit like onSubmit={(event) => this.props.handleSubmit(event)}
Sometimes we don't need to specify event object for onSubmit like onSubmi={this.handleSubmit}. 
I'm not sure if you guys understand my question